# Want to clean up contacts

Tags: macos, mac, contacts

Years ago I thought I was going to be smart and import 6000 contacts to my database. Several mail systems and mail clients later, I would now like to clean this up down to about the 800-1000 that I actually need.

I can identify the ones to delete because they have an address, but no phone or email. 
I am using google apps for business, mail & address book.

I thought if I could just get everything in to a mail client that sorts contacts better, I could sort and manually delete. That would synch accross systems and voila - clean. Problem is I need to look for address with no email or phone number associated in a certain zip code.

I made and archive of my contacts. What I am trying to avoid is exporting all, cleaning in excel, then deleting everything and re-importing all.

Tried thunderbird. no go. tried entourage, but it is not importing all my contacts.

Comment: Automator might be useful in clearing contacts to your criteria

Answer (score 1):

You could use Automator to filter the contacts according to that criteria. I haven't actually tried it, and I'm including a screenshot with some of the conditions I'd use just for reference. But still, this might help.[image]